# Can the GY-906 (meant for Arduino) be used on Raspberry?

Tags: pi-4, temperature

I want to use a sensor to detect the temperature of a person. I have this sensor which is used for Arduino and I'm wondering if it can be used on the Raspberry Pi 4. Otherwise, what other choices do I have to accurately measure human temperature?

Comment: Ah, anything Anono can do, Rpi can do better. GY906 IR actually is not only for Anono, but for everybody: You might like to check if yours is similar to this one, or let me know the link so I can have a look..https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32901785164.html?spm=2114.search0302.3.9.318b26e1WC0oer&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=d1bbb468-ba87-45a3-9bff-c7f99692e463&algo_expid=d1bbb468-ba87-45a3-9bff-c7f99692e463-1. Cheers.

Comment: I'm using this one: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32910533502.html?gps-id=pcDetail404&scm=1007.16891.96945.0&scm_id=1007.16891.96945.0&scm-url=1007.16891.96945.0&pvid=a178b8f2-7a30-4805-8826-dd673c689a24&_t=gps-id:pcDetail404,scm-url:1007.16891.96945.0,pvid:a178b8f2-7a30-4805-8826-dd673c689a24,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2364_668%23808%234094%23182_668%23888%233325%232_668%232846%238113%23617_668%232717%237560%23240__668%233374%2315176%23914

Comment: Oh my goodness. I have never seen this long distance GY906. I have a couple of IR temp sensor but all cheap things. Your high class thing is 10 times more expensive than mine. I once looked for this for covid app. Let me have a quick google and come back to you later.

Comment: I am back. I quickly googled that it is using the following: MLX90614 I2C 17 bit ADC family / Single and Dual Zone Infra Red Thermometer in TO-39 Datasheet - Melexis
https://datasheet.octopart.com/MLX90614ESF-DCI-000-SP-Melexis-datasheet-12517428.pdf. I skimmed the data sheet and found that it is using a small subset of standard SMBus commands. If you already know that Anono can do it, Rpi can do it better, with 90% certainty. But I am just a poor friendly hobbyist. I have never played this high class thing before. No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up. Good luck and cheers.